# bootstrap 4 class to make nav brand image only appear at and after medium

Tags: image, class, bootstrap-4, nav

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">

      <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img class="navbar-brand  d-sm-none d-md-block" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>



      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicer</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Trailer List</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

i want the nav brand image to only appear at medium and above. when i shrink down to small it re-appears and over the hamburger tab. what class would i have to use and additional addons to the class? .col? .d? d-breakpoint? im new to this so cut me some slack just trying to figure it out. i keep re watching the bootstrap 4 section in colt steel's web developer bootcamp and keep missing something. sucks learning alone

Comment: Can you please give me any image so that i can use that image in place of logo? and what do you want to do by using these classes .col and .d please give me some hint so that i can explain you how you can use these classes.

Comment: how do i send it to you? it wont let me attach it here in the reply box.

Answer (score 0):

### See and tell me are you want this or something different. Then, let me know what do you want in nav so that i can help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<div class="container">
 
  

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <img class="navbar-brand  d-sm-none d-md-block" src="img/logo.png">
  </a>
  
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicer</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Trailer List</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```